# How to make a circular button in android using react-native's TouchableNativeFeedback?

Tags: android, react-native

With `TouchableHighlight`, I can easily make circular buttons using `width`, `height`, and `borderRadius` style properties.

However, `borderRadius` seems to be having no effect at all for `TouchableNativeFeedback`

I have tried wrapping the `TouchableNativeFeedback` element in a view with a `borderRadius` and `overflow: 'hidden'`, but to no avail.

Would be glad to get some help here. Thanks.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` doesn't work properly on Android. But could you elaborate a bit why it's mandatory to use `TouchableNativeFeedback` in your case? I mean, there could be alternative solutions for your problem.

Comment: @zvona Mainly for the ripple effect on buttons. Finishing up an app, and  `TouchableNativeFeedback` kind of ups the UI by a notch when compared to `TouchableHighlight`. Not really a deal breaker, but something nice to have

Comment: Does my answer solve your issue @kapv89? 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to set the `borderRadius` on a parent `<View>` around the `<TouchableNativeFeedback>`, and use the `TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('your_color', true)` method in the background prop (note, the borderless arg. set to true).

As described by **reyeser** [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6480#issuecomment-234846355) in react-native github issues.

Answer (score 9):

Copyable example of **Brad Adams** answer:

```
<View style={{ borderRadius: 15, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
  <TouchableNativeFeedback background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('#000000', true)}>
</View>
```

Edit: for some reason, somebody thought that I was copying an answer, but I just wanted to make a clear working example available

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it looks like `TouchableNativeFeedback` doesn't support `borderRadius`.

You could try tweaking the code of `TouchableNativeFeedback` and sending a pull request or implementing a new view (Android circular button) and releasing it to npm. See [docs on writing views](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html).

You could also look for an existing component that does what you need: https://js.coach. Searching for 'button' gives me a few results.